# Heroku - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR: column "requested" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, rails-activerecord

I have an `absense.html.erb` which works fine in development and production. However when I try to access the page I get the following error:

> 2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/absence" for
>   77.100.90.77 at 2013-03-25 18:43:43 +0000 2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00 app[web.1]:  2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "requested"
>   does not exist 2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...LECT
>   "holidays".* FROM "holidays"  WHERE (state = "requested...
>   2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   ^ 2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "holidays".* FROM
>   "holidays"  WHERE (state = "requested")): 2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00
>   app[web.1]:  2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app/controllers/holidays_controller.rb:52:in `absence'
>   2013-03-25T18:43:43+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path=/rota_days host=miuk-portal.herokuapp.com fwd="77.100.90.77"
>   dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=5773ms status=200
>   bytes=897173

The error points to the following line of my absense method in my controller

```
def absence
#show the holidays where the approver id matches the current user id
#and state = "requested"'

    @user = current_user
    if current_user.role? :administrator
      # a superadmin can view all current holiday requests
      @holidays = Holiday.find(:all, :conditions => 'state = "requested"')
    else
      #otherwise an admin sees the holiday requests that they are approvers for
      @holidays = Holiday.find(:all, :conditions => ["approver_id = #{current_user.id}", "state = requested"])
    end
  end
```

I have declared this in my holiday model as shown below:

**Holiday.rb**

```
class Holiday < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
  belongs_to :type, :class_name => "Type"
  belongs_to :approver, :class_name => "User"


  before_create :default_values #Before creating holiday set default_values
                                #before_create :overflow


  validates :start_at, :presence => { :message => "must be a valid date/time" }
  validates :end_at, :presence => {:message => "must be a valid date/time"}
  validate :start_must_be_before_end_date
  validate :overflow #Hook method to determine if user holidays are over the set amount
  validates_presence_of :end_at, :start_at

  attr_accessible :description, :end_at, :start_at, :state, :type_id, :user_id, :color


  def length
    (self.end_at.to_i - self.start_at.to_i)/(60*60*24)
  end

  def days_used
    ( (start_at.to_date)..(end_at.to_date) ).select {|d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size
  end


  #Validates_presence_of is called to ensure that the start date exisit.
  #Start date must be lt or = to end date otherwise throw error.
  def start_must_be_before_end_date
    errors.add(:start_at, "must be before end date") unless
        self.start_at <= self.end_at
  end

  #Overflow of holidays is validated by calling "validates" L31. Then checks if absent days
  #Is gt or = to length
  def overflow
    errors.add(:overflow, "- You only have #{user.absentdays} days holiday remaining; this absence is #{length} days.") unless
        user.absentdays >= length
  end

  def name
    return self.user.name
  end

  def colors
    if state ||= "denied"
      return self.color ||= "#C00000"

    end
  end

  private

  #Setting default values - before_create is called and sets the following
  def default_values
    self.state ||= "requested"
    self.color ||= "#000000"
    self.type_id||= 1
  end
end
```

Don't seem to understand why this works in both development and production and not in heroku. Any ideas?

Comment: You might just need to migrate your database with `heroku run rake db:migrate`. Don't forget to restart your app afterwards with `heroku restart` for it to pick up these changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard SQL strings use single quotes, double quotes are for identifiers (such as table and column names); PostgreSQL follows the standard here, MySQL and SQLite are less strict, other databases do other things with varying amounts of strictness. In any case, single quotes for SQL string literals should work the same everywhere.

You're using double quotes on an SQL string:

```
@holidays = Holiday.find(:all, :conditions => 'state = "requested"')
#------------------------------------------------------^---------^
```

You must single quotes:

```
@holidays = Holiday.find(:all, :conditions => %q{state = 'requested'})
```

or modernize it and let ActiveRecord deal with the quoting:

```
@holidays = Holiday.where(:state => 'requested')
```

You'll probably need to fix the quoting for this one too:

```
@holidays = Holiday.find(:all, :conditions => ["approver_id = #{current_user.id}", "state = requested"])
```

Again, modernizing it is the easiest way:

```
@holidays = Holiday.where(:approver_id => current_user.id, :state => 'requested')
```

I'm guessing that you're developing on SQLite but deploying on PostgreSQL. That's a bad idea, always develop and deploy on the same stack.

Comment: I realised :P after I just posted this. Learn something everyday. And I am developing on MySQL

Comment: The modernized way looks better much cleaner approach

Comment: @user532339: It is also chainable (`M.where(...).where(...).order(...)`) which is rather convenient.