# Problems with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have used MySQL for years, now I need to use Postgresql.

I am having tons of problems getting trivial SQL to work and I have no clue as to why it does not work.

First here is my data:

```
Momentive-> \d+ "OHLCData";
Did not find any relation named ""OHLCData"".
Momentive-> \d+ "MomentiveData"."OHLCData";
                                                             Table "MomentiveDat
a.OHLCData"
    Column     |       Type       |                                  Modifiers
                                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------
---------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 ohlc_id       | integer          | not null default nextval('"MomentiveData"."O
HLCData_ohlc_id_seq"'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 OHLCDataSetID | integer          | not null
                                 | plain    |              |
 Date          | character(20)    | not null
                                 | extended |              |
 EpochTime     | integer          | not null
                                 | plain    |              |
 Open          | double precision | not null
                                 | plain    |              |
 High          | double precision | not null
                                 | plain    |              |
 Low           | double precision | not null
                                 | plain    |              |
 Close         | double precision | not null
                                 | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "OHLCData_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ohlc_id)
    "Date" btree ("Date")
    "EpochTime" btree ("EpochTime")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "OHLCData_OHLCDataSetID_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("OHLCDataSetID") REFERENCES "Mome
ntiveData"."OHLCDataSets"("OHLCDataSetID")
Has OIDs: no
```

First question, why do I need to always put the schema name in front of it to do anything with a table?   Is there an equivalent to "use database" from MySQL?

I am purposefully storing the date info as a string because of my apps needs.  So I want to enter a "trivial" select such as:

```
SELECT * FROM "MomentiveData"."OHLCData" AS t1 WHERE t1."Date" >= "2010-01-03 00:00:00" AND t1."Date" <= "2010-01-03 23:59:59";
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in query: ERROR: column "2010-01-03 00:00:00" does not exist
LINE 1: ...omentiveData"."OHLCData" AS t1 WHERE t1."Date" >= "2010-01-0...
```

WTF? how is it confusing my data point with a column name?
How should that be structured?

Thanx

PS, I used adminer.php to create the table, I used psql for examples.  I actually have the table populated.

Comment: In SQL99, single quotes are for string values, double quotes are for columns

Comment: I never used myself but `SET search_path TO "MomentiveData",public;` might work.

Comment: Also relevant: [Heroku - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR: column “requested” does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15622552/479863) and [switching from MySQL to PostgreSQL for Ruby on Rails for the sake of Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8736041/479863).

Comment: The equivalent (in this case) to `use database` would be `set schema='database'`. But using the `search_path` is probably more flexible. You can also change the `search_path` permanently by using `alter user set search_path=...`.

Comment: Man I feel stupid about the quotes, in MySQL I used back ticks and just forgot about the strings.  Thanx, I will also play with the set schema and search_path ideas.